# Is it good to store all the fetched data from api call in redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

As I know, redux is a single store. So it made me think to store all the fetched data into redux store so all the components can access the data. Is it right to do that? If not what can be stored in redux?

Answer (score 0):

From the official website (https://redux.js.org/faq/general):

```
I would like to amend this: don't use Redux until you have problems with vanilla React.
```

You don't need Redux for this, you can do it in vanilla React. And in general in software development it is a good practice to not use something unless you need it.

If you want more reasons why you shouldn't do this, check the description of this question: ["If the data comes from the backend store it in Redux"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72233383/if-the-data-comes-from-the-backend-store-it-in-redux)